# Cron Job to move files not running

Tags: cron

I added this command in my crontab, but it's not working. I saved in both my user and root crontab but neither is working.

```
* * * * * [ $(ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && [ $(ps aux | grep mv | grep -v grep | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && mv /media/cyper/evo_1tb/*.plot /media/cyper/Farm5

grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

shows it is being executed, but no files are being copied.

```
May 22 23:53:01 Plotter CRON[1010104]: (root) CMD ([ $(ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && [ $(ps aux | grep mv | grep -v grep | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && mv /media/cyper/evo_1tb/*.plot /media/cyper/Farm5)
May 22 23:53:01 Plotter CRON[1010105]: (cyper) CMD ([ $(ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && [ $(ps aux | grep mv | grep -v grep | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && mv /media/cyper/evo_1tb/*.plot /media/cyper/Farm5)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no copy command in your crontab.  Did you mean "moved"?  Don't make your crontab commandline too complex, create a script that does the dirty work and let cron start that script.

If this command does run for other users too, this one may detect a running "mv" from one of those, and decide not to run itself.

Comment: Yes, sorry moved. Like cut and paste. This script works for at least 2 other persons and I copied it just editing the paths. 
There are files with .plot extensions in /media/cyper/evo_1tb and needs moving to /media/cyper/Farm5 one by one.
This is the required job: [check if there IS plot file] && [check if mv command IS NOT running] && [move the files]

Any ideas?

Comment: In that case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: SIMPLE ! - just add all the commands in a script and then add that script in your cron job

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for “any ideas”, I’ll give some:

- Run the command from the command line. 
  If that doesn’t work, *debug that.*

  If it *does* work from the command line, continue:
- Follow [Gerard’s advice](https://serverfault.com/q/1064430/201794#1064431): put the command into a script,
  debug the script, and then run the script from cron.

  If that’s not acceptable, or you try it and it doesn’t work, continue:
- For debugging purposes, stop running it every minute. 
  Run it every 10 minutes (with `*/10 * * * *`)
  or every 15 minutes (with `*/15 * * * *`).
- Break down the command to see where it fails. 
  For example, try
  `ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l >> /home/cyper/cron.log`

  If that fails to give you a positive number as a result,
  break it down further to see where it fails and where it works. 
  If the above succeeds (gives you a positive number), try
  `[ $(ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l) -gt 0 ] &&     ps aux | grep mv | grep -v grep | wc -l >> /home/cyper/cron.log`

  Same process. 
  If that fails to give you a zero as a result,
  break it down further to see where it fails and where it works. 
  If the above succeeds (gives you zero), try
  `blah blah blah  &&  blah blah blah  &&  mv /media/cyper/evo_1tb/*.plot /media/cyper/Farm5 >> /home/cyper/cron.log 2>&1`
  and so on.

---

OK, you say you’re getting

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.OddU6i/crontab":23: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can’t install.
```

Well, that’s an error message from `crontab`, and it’s written in English. 
Did you read it? 
It says “bad minute” —
that means that the minute(s) field is not written correctly. 
You say “It's the exact same line.”
(I presume that you are referring to the `ls` command). 
That’s not relevant at this point. 
What do you have ***before*** the `ls`? 
`* * * * *`? 
`*/10 * * * *`? 
`*/15 * * * *`? 
Or something else? 
That’s where you need to be looking now.

P.S. Did you look in your mail file? 
It’s probably `/var/mail/cyper`.

Comment: ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l >> /home/cyper/cron.log

If I execute this manually in terminal it works and so it prints a number in the destination file.
But when I try to save it in crontab it tells me:
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.OddU6i/crontab":23: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.

It's the exact same line. Could the problem be that I am working using TeamViewer from Windows. I read that it might be putting the wrong line breaks or something, but not sure how to check.

Comment: See  update above.

Comment: If's it's being run every minute according to /var/log/syslog does it mean there is an issue with the minute? The full command is in the OP.

Btw I created a script https://i.imgur.com/O6J02Ej.png
When I run it manually in Terminal I get this: https://i.imgur.com/Z5jjNxd.png

I am not sure how to interpret the output?

Comment: (1) ITSM that you’re confusing apples and oranges.  Your ***original*** command, given in the question — the very long one beginning `* * * * * [ $(ls -al /media/cyper/evo_1tb | grep plot | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && …` — is running every minute.  Then you tried something I suggested, ending `>> /home/cyper/cron.log`, and you got an error message.  Are telling me that ***that second command*** is also now running every minute? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Thanks for taking the initiative to add the `set -v -x` to the script.  (3) The last line of the output from your script shows that ``ps aux | grep mv | grep -v grep | wc -l`` is outputting `3`.  So it believes that three `mv` processes are running, and therefore it is not proceeding.  So the next step is to run ``ps aux | grep mv | grep -v grep`` (without the `wc`), with output to the screen or redirected to a file, and see what’s happening.